# Check folder sizes and report combined size for identical named folders in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, disk-space

I have 2 folders that have subfolders (named after users). Most subfolder names exist in both folders, but not all. Now I want to create a list of space used by each user.

I can use the following command to get a list for each folder,

```
du -m --max-depth=1 | sort -nr
```

but I don't know an easy way to merge two of these lists. Not all users have a folder in both places, so simple sorting does not work. Any idea on how to sum up the folder sizes for each user?

Comment: I don't quite get your folders structure. Could you give a simple example to clarify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
join -j 2 <(cd dir1; du -m --max-depth=1 | sort -k2,2) <(cd dir2; du -m --max-depth=1 | sort -k2,2) | awk '{print $2 + $3, $1}' | sort -nr
```

It should look like this:

```
11 ./bob
9 ./jan
8 ./cheryl
3 ./mike
```

You can change the AWK command to make the output a little more attractive:

```
awk '{printf "%6s\t%s\n", $2 + $3, $1}'
```

which will right-align the numbers and make the names line up in a column.

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly. I didn't know about the join command, that's really handy.